# How to make th and btn-group have same expression?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my project, I use bootstrap.

There is a table in my page with six thead .

One of these theads is "stat" which is different from others.

Here is my code:

```
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>one</th>
            <th>two</th>
            <th>three</th>
            <th>
            <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            stat<span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            ...
            </ul>
            </div>
            </th>
            <th>four</th>
            <th>five</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    ....
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

But th stat has different background expression.

What i want is like that:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">one</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">two</button>

 <div class="btn-group" role="group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  stat
  <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

These elems of one, two and stat looks like the same. 
But unlucky, they are not in table.

Who can help me?

Comment: Do you want the table headings to be like the dropdown? Or do you want the dropdown to be more like the table headings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "stat" is different because it uses "button" but not on another field. 
change this code

```
<div class="btn-group">
 <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
 stat<span class="caret"></span></button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      ...
 </ul>
</div>
```

To this code

```
<div class="btn-group">
 <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  <b>stat</b><span class="caret"></span>
 </a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  ...
 </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this help you, good luck.

Comment: How will this help? one two and stat are all `button`s in the OP's question?

Comment: Ah, I see now, you left out the style classes.